# Pass data between events of HttpApplication in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am looking for a way to pass data between events of HttpApplication. For example, I have the following code in my HTTP module:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += DoFoo;
    context.EndRequest += DoBar;
}
```

I want to save some data during `BeginRequest` event in the `DoFoo` method and access it later during the `EndRequest` event in the `DoBar` method.

As far as I am aware, `Session` is not available at this point yet. Is there a way to store the data between events so that it is:

1. Available in the current and all subsequent events;
2. Accessible in only in the scope of the current request.

**Update:**

Is it possible to use HTTP module instance variables to achieve this? Is there any risk that the data stored in these variables would be accessible outside the current request?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.8) help?

Comment: @wazz, thank you for the link. I have scanned through this MSDN page before posting my question on StackOverflow. Unfortunately it doesn't have any information about passing data between events.

Comment: You’re looking for [HttpContext.Item](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/difference-between-httpcontext-current-items-and-httpcontext/)

Comment: @JohnWu, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per John Wo's comment under my question, my problem was solved by using `HttpContext.Items`. [This is the link to the article provided by John](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/difference-between-httpcontext-current-items-and-httpcontext/).

Example of using `HttpContext.Items`:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += DoFoo;
    context.EndRequest += DoBar;
}

private void DoFoo(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
    httpApplication.Context.Items.Add("MyFlag", true);
}

private void DoBar(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
    if(httpApplication.Context.Items.Contains("MyFlag") && (bool)contextItems["MyFlag"] == true)
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure when Session is first available but I'm able to access it with this little-known event in Global.asax, fwiw:

```
// This event is executed for every page request
// and is run before the PreInit event.
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ok"] = "OK";
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to pass the data between event in an HTTP module and I am getting errors at runtime when trying to access the Session there. I believe this is because the HTTP modules are run before the page is returned to the browser, when Session is not yet initialised or is in read-only state.